# Add blocks on an existing page

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I'm new in Magento and I'm still learning how to deal with blocks. I am trying to add a form on an existing page (Product view for example). I'm trying to do that by adding a block with my form. But I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What kind of block? Magento1 or Magento2

Comment: I'm using magento 1.9.. It's just a block to show up a file upload button

Comment: did you create the upload button block?

Answer (score 2):

add below code into local.xml of your theme

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/template" name="custom.block" as="customBlock" template="<PATH TO PHTML FILE>"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```